Databricks Error: Multiple sources found for iceberg - Uniform Iceberg Read & the Iceberg runtime jar
Using Azure Databricks in runtime 14.3 LTS and trying to use the hadoop catalog, for testing out an apache iceberg storage implementation I get an error when I try and write a table:

Multiple sources found for iceberg (com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.uniform.sources.IcebergBrowseOnlyDataSource, org.apache.iceberg.spark.source.IcebergSource), please specify the fully qualified class name.

Is there a way to override databricks's uniform reader to allow for us to use the apache iceberg runtime exclusively on our cluster?
My spark cluster configurations are:

policy: unrestricted, multinode
Access mode: no isolation shared
1-1 Worker 16-16 GB Memory 4-4 Cores
1 Driver 16 GB Memory, 4 Cores
Runtime 14.3.x-scala2.12
Photon
Standard_D4ds_v5
4 DBU/h

My spark config is:

spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.warehouse /test_data/
spark.hadoop.fs.wasbs.impl org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem
spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog
spark.hadoop.fs.abfss.impl org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem
spark.databricks.sql.iceberg.handle-tables false
spark.sql.extensions org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions
spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type hadoop

Libraries installed on the cluster:

com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:8.6.6

dbfs:/FileStore/jars/bf401b66_66f7_46c8_9964_b6ad07ad8099/data_lake_library-0.2.1.dev59+unknown-py3-none-any.whl (custom team built wheel)

numpy==1.26.4

org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.4.0

org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client-runtime:3.4.0

org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.12:1.5.2

pandas==2.2.2

pyarrow==7.0.0


Simple code:
import logging
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from data_lake_library.config.config import AzureKeyVaultParams
from data_lake_library.config.secrets_manager import AzureKeyVaultSecrets

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def main():
    # Key Vault name and secret name for retrieving credentials
    keyvault_name = ""  # Replace with your actual Key Vault name 
    secret_name = ""  # Replace with your actual secret name in Key Vault

    # Initialize Azure Key Vault
    logger.info(f"Initializing Azure Key Vault with name: {keyvault_name}")
    akv_params = AzureKeyVaultParams(keyvault_name=keyvault_name)
    akv = AzureKeyVaultSecrets(params=akv_params)

    # Retrieve the SAS token from Key Vault
    logger.info(f"Retrieving secret from Azure Key Vault: {secret_name}")
    access_token = akv.get_secret(secret_name)
    logger.info("Successfully retrieved SAS token from Azure Key Vault")

    # Set ADLS Gen2 configurations (service principal, OAuth token, or account key)
    storage_account_name = "" # adls storage account name
    container_name = "" # container using to test

    # Initialize Spark session
    logger.info("Initializing Spark session.")
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("Iceberg ADLS Gen2 Example") \
        .config(f"fs.azure.account.key.{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net", access_token) \
        .getOrCreate()

    logger.info("Spark session created successfully.")

    # Define the table path where the Iceberg table will be stored in ADLS Gen2
    table_path = f"abfss://{container_name}@{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/my_database/my_iceberg_table"

    # Create a new database in ADLS Gen2 under the Hadoop-based Iceberg catalog
    logger.info("Creating database in ADLS Gen2 under the Hadoop-based Iceberg catalog.")
    spark.sql("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS spark_catalog.my_database")
    logger.info("Database created successfully (if not already present).")

    # Create an Iceberg table with an explicit path for storage in ADLS Gen2
    logger.info("Creating Iceberg table in ADLS Gen2.")
    spark.sql(f"""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS spark_catalog.my_database.my_iceberg_table (
            col1 INT,
            col2 STRING
        )
        USING iceberg
    """)
    logger.info(f"Iceberg table created successfully at location: {table_path}")

    # Stop the Spark session
    logger.info("Stopping Spark session.")
    spark.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Full error:

Multiple sources found for iceberg
(com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.uniform.sources.IcebergBrowseOnlyDataSource,
org.apache.iceberg.spark.source.IcebergSource), please specify the
fully qualified class name. File , line 62
59     spark.stop()
61 if name == "main":
---> 62     main() File , line 48, in main()
46 # Create an Iceberg table with an explicit path for storage in ADLS Gen2
47 logger.info("Creating Iceberg table in ADLS Gen2.")
---> 48 spark.sql(f"""
49     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS spark_catalog.my_database.my_iceberg_table (
50         col1 INT,
51         col2 STRING
52     )
53     USING iceberg
54 """)
55 logger.info(f"Iceberg table created successfully at location: {table_path}")
57 # Stop the Spark session File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/instrumentation_utils.py:47, in
_wrap_function..wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
45 start = time.perf_counter()
46 try:
---> 47     res = func(*args, **kwargs)
48     logger.log_success(
49         module_name, class_name, function_name, time.perf_counter() - start, signature
50     )
51     return res File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py:1748, in
SparkSession.sql(self, sqlQuery, args, **kwargs)    1744
assert self._jvm is not None    1745         litArgs =
self._jvm.PythonUtils.toArray(    1746
[_to_java_column(lit(v)) for v in (args or [])]    1747         )
-> 1748     return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery, litArgs), self)    1749 finally:    1750     if len(kwargs) > 0: File
/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1355,
in JavaMember.call(self, *args)    1349 command =
proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\    1350     self.command_header +\    1351
args_command +\    1352     proto.END_COMMAND_PART    1354 answer =
self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1355 return_value = get_return_value(    1356     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1358 for temp_arg
in temp_args:    1359     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"): File
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py:230, in
capture_sql_exception..deco(*a, **kw)
226 converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
227 if not isinstance(converted, UnknownException):
228     # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
229     # JVM exception message.
--> 230     raise converted from None
231 else:
232     raise


does my solution working for you?

This error raised because there is 2 class found for the format iceberg
com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.uniform.sources.IcebergBrowseOnlyDataSource and org.apache.iceberg.spark.source.IcebergSource.
So, in databricks you use the Delta Lake Universal Format (UniForm) to create table with the iceberg source.
Code
storage_account_name = "jadls"
container_name = "data"


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Iceberg ADLS Gen2 Example").config(f"fs.azure.account.key.{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net", access_token).getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog","org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog") 
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type","hadoop")
table_path = f"abfss://{container_name}@{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/iceberg/warehouse1"
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.warehouse",table_path)
spark.sql("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS spark_catalog.my_database")

spark.sql("""
    CREATE TABLE spark_catalog.my_database.my_iceberg_table2  (id bigint, data string) 
    TBLPROPERTIES(
  'delta.enableIcebergCompatV2' = 'true',
  'delta.universalFormat.enabledFormats' = 'iceberg');
  """)

and describe the table.

and in storage account.

